# How to change default Float to Float32 in a local Julia environment?

Tags: julia

My default `Float` type is `Float64`, however, I want to change that to `Float32` as they are faster on my machine. I can set a global constant like `const Float = Float32`, but that forces me to use `Float32` constructor everywhere. I wonder if there were a way to set the default float in a local environment.

Comment: `Float32` is normally faster on most computers, as far as I know. And if you want that extra speed you use an explicit constructor, or literal syntax, such as `4.2f0` instead of `4.2`, and `1.3f-6` instead of `1.3e-6`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the package [`ChangePrecision.jl`](https://github.com/stevengj/ChangePrecision.jl) to change the precision of numeric literals in a block of code:

```
julia> using ChangePrecision

julia> @changeprecision Float32 begin
           x = 7.3
           y = 1/3
           z = rand() .+ ones(3,4)
       end
3×4 Matrix{Float32}:
 1.20411  1.20411  1.20411  1.20411
 1.20411  1.20411  1.20411  1.20411
 1.20411  1.20411  1.20411  1.20411

julia> typeof.((x, y, z))
(Float32, Float32, Matrix{Float32})
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `ChangePrecision` are the [`SafeREPL`](https://github.com/rfourquet/SafeREPL.jl) and [`SwapLiterals`](https://github.com/rfourquet/SafeREPL.jl#how-to-use-in-source-code) packages:

```
julia> using SwapLiterals

julia> @swapliterals Float64 => Float32 begin
           @show typeof(1.0)
           1.0 + 2.0
       end
typeof(1.0f0) = Float32
3.0f0
```

`SafeREPL` uses `SwapLiterals` to change the interpretation of literals at the REPL:

```
julia> using SafeREPL

julia> swapliterals!(Float64 => Float32)

julia> 1.0, typeof(1.0)
(1.0f0, Float32)
```

But unlike `ChangePrecision`, these packages don't change how `rand` and other functions work, e.g.

```
 julia> @swapliterals Float64 => Float32 begin
           x = 7.3
           y = 1/3
           z = rand() .+ ones(3,4)
           typeof.((x, y, z))
       end
(Float32, Float64, Matrix{Float64})
```